# .Net Machinekey.Protect - what algorithm is used?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.5

I'm using Machinekey.Protect and Machinekey.Unprotect to encrypt values in my application. A potential client is performing a security audit and has asked about the encryption algorithms used by this method and I am struggling to find an answer using google.

Any help with verifiable links would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
John

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/10/22/cryptographic-improvements-in-asp-net-4-5-pt-1.aspx

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The encryption & hashing algorithms are specified in the [`<machineKey>` element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/w8h3skw9%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) in Web.config.

The default is AES256.

Comment: Minor nit: If you're using an auto-generated <machineKey>, the default algorithm for MachineKey.Protect is actually AES-256. Otherwise the ASP.NET runtime respects the algorithm and key length that you specify explicitly in <machineKey>.

Comment: @Levi: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/10/22/cryptographic-improvements-in-asp-net-4-5-pt-1.aspx says 192? Or did that change in 4.5?

Comment: @SLaks: That page in particular talks about ASP.NET 4.0, where auto-gen uses AES-192 (with 160 bits of entropy). Check the following day's post (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/10/23/cryptographic-improvements-in-asp-net-4-5-pt-2.aspx) for ASP.NET 4.5, where auto-gen uses AES-256 (with a full 256 bits of entropy).

Comment: @SLaks Do you know why the descriptionKey and validationKey for MachineKey are respectively 256 and 512 bit long? My guess is that is for supporting 512 bit algorithms but if you use AES256 it just uses half of both keys?