# MachineKey - Is it strongly secured to use Machinekey.Protect?

Tags: c#, security, encryption, rijndael, machinekey

- Is MachineKey.Protect strongly secured? or I should find other encryption algorythms like Rijndael?
- What are MachineKey.Protect disadventages?

I want to use encryption for email verification link and it must be strongly secured

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It uses whatever is set in [`MachineKeySection.ValidationAlgorithm`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.machinekeysection.validationalgorithm(v=vs.110).aspx) in the appropriate config file.

Comment: I understand that, but is it strongly protected? Is it safe to use? or I must use another way for encoding, for example Rijndael. ??

Comment: The default aes algorithm is an implementation of Rijndael. http://stackoverflow.com/a/20497853/413180

Comment: It is as strong as the algorithm you choose.